# Facebook Pop fragment from Obj-C into Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-pop

Working on a departed coworkers project. I need to implement this objective-C code for this Facebook Pop animation into Swift. I will just paste it in its entirety since only a few lines long. I've looked at a few tutorials but being new at Pop and Swift has made this tricky. How would I write this in Swift?

```
- (void)scaleDownView:(UIView *)view
{
  POPSpringAnimation *scaleAnimation = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerScaleXY];
  scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0.1, 0.1)];
  scaleAnimation.springBounciness = 6.f;
  [view.layer pop_addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scaleAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with this question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've added a bridging header to the project in question. Imported `#import <pop/POP.h>` in the bridging header. 
You'll have to `import pop` at the top of any `Swift` file you'd like to use the below method.

```
    func scaleDownView(view: UIView) {
        let scaleAnimation = POPSpringAnimation(propertyNamed:kPOPLayerScaleXY)
        scaleAnimation.toValue = NSValue(CGSize: CGSize(width: 0.1, height: 0.1))
        scaleAnimation.springBounciness = 6.0
        view.layer.pop_addAnimation(scaleAnimation, forKey: "scaleAnimation")
    }
```